# Photos from Onedrive, view only, no downloading?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I use onedrive to store all my photos, the space for all these photos is over 80G. I use a yoga 11s with an 128GB SSD. So there is no way for me to sync all my photos to my pc.

Is there any way to browse photos from onedrive only, without downloading? Or is there any other album apps in the MS store?

Thanks for helping! New to win8.1 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Windows 8.1, you should see all the files in your OneDrive, even if they aren't downloaded locally to your computer. In Explorer you should see these files as "Online Only" indicating they are only available when you are online and connected to the internet.

Various applications should be able to interact with these files, like the Photos app in Windows. This way you can browse all of your photos without keeping them on your laptop.

Comment: I initially turned OneDrive off, because I was afraid that OneDrive files would take all the space of my SSD. But after I turned it back on, OneDrive started downloading everything. May I ask how to switch to the "online only" option? thanks!

Comment: If you launch the OneDrive app, then bring up the charms bar, select Settings, and then Options, and then click Make all files online-only, it should stop everything from being downloaded.

Comment: Thank you RGregg! This is the correct answer! I need more reputation to vote-up, so thank you again! :)